# How do I see cookies I am sending programmatically in spring mvc using Postman?

Tags: spring, cookies, postman

I am binding a cookie with a post request using the code

`@CookieValue(value = "foo", defaultValue = "hello") String fooCookie` .

Is this code in the controller along with get/post enough for setting a default cookie with name as "foo", and value as "hello"?

I want to see the cookie in the response sent back by the server through postman and postman intercepter. I am using the test script

`var myval = postman.getresponseCookie("foo").value;
postman.setGlobalVariable("foo",myval.value);`

or

`tests['cookiesets'] = postman.getResponseCookie("name").value;` .

I am beginner, hence please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below should work in Postman Test and should print cookie value in Tests tab of response.

```
var cookieValue  = postman.getResponseCookie("foo").value;
tests["cookie-value = " + cookieValue] = true;
```

And if you want to verify returned cookie value then use something like

```
tests["cookie-value-correct"] = cookieValue === "hello";
```

Comment: `There was an error evaluating the test script. Cannot read property 'value' of null.` I get an error executing your first script.

Comment: Check your service what is the cookie name and if it's value is not null. The scripts are working fine for me. You can also check name and value of cookie in postman's Cookies tab in response.

Comment: I do not get any name and values in the postman's cookies tab. My http status is 200 ok and I get the return string but I am struggling to see whether the cookie is set or not. Also, i cannot see it in postman.

Comment: *return string means I am returning a string in response body.

Comment: Are there any configuration required in server to accept cookies? As your code snippet wrong wonderfully in my local but fails in the server.